# Select tag is rerendering in React JS

Tags: reactjs, select, jsx, rerender

I want to display data from nested array. Displayed data will be changed with next & prev buttons and from select menu. But I want to update default option in select menu to show witch part (and page) of data is shown now. Because it's not possible to Dynamically change *defaultValue* of select tag in ReactJS I put select tag inside *div* tag & give *div* key={changableValue}. I give same value to to select tag (defaultValue={changableValue}) & it worked. default option updates in select on every render. but after several click on next button select tag rerenders (and rerenders). How can I stop that rerendering?

```
export default function App() {
  const [part, setPart] = useState(0);
  const [partVal, setPartVal] = useState(0);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [pageVal, setPageVal] = useState(0);
  // data
  const pics = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
  ];

  const next = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
    setPageVal(page + 1);
    if (page == pics[part].length - 1 && part != pics.length - 1) {
      setPart(part + 1);
      setPage(0);
      setPartVal(part + 1);
    } else if (part == pics.length - 1 && page == pics[part].length - 1) {
      setPart(0);
      setPage(0);
      setPartVal(part + 1);
    }
  };

  const prev = () => {
    setPage(page - 1);
    setPageVal(page - 1);
    if (page == 0 && part != 0) {
      setPart(part - 1);
      setPage(0);
      setPartVal(part + 1);
    } else if (part == 0 && page == 0) {
      setPart(pics.length - 1);
      setPage(0);
      setPartVal(part + 1);
    }
  };

  const changePart = (e) => {
    setPart(parseInt(e.target.value) - 1);
    setPage(0);
    setPageVal(0);
  };
  return (
    <div>

      <label htmlFor="part">Choose part:</label>
      <div key={partVal}>
        <select id="part" onChange={changePart} defaultValue={partVal}>
          {pics.map((i, index) => (
            <option key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 999)} value={index}>
              part: {index + 1}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>

      <label htmlFor="page">Choose page:</label>
      <div key={pageVal}>
        <select
          id="page"
          onChange={(e) => setPage(parseInt(e.target.value))}
          defaultValue={pageVal}
        >
          {pics[part].map((i, index) => (
            <option key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 999)} value={index}>
              {index + 1}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>{pics[part][page]}</div>

      <button onClick={prev}>prev</button>
      <button onClick={next}>next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-chandrasekhar-q9cqg?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is You can change defaultValue to value
you can search and know what is different between controlled input and uncontrolled input in ReactJS

- controlled

> In a controlled component, form data is handled by a React component.

- uncontrolled

> The alternative is uncontrolled components, where form data is handled
> by the DOM itself. To write an uncontrolled component, instead of
> writing an event handler for every state update, you can use a ref
> to get form values from the DOM.

Simply :

- when You use onChange in your input use [value]
- when you use ref or id to change [read,or change value for input ] use [defaultValue]